# Shift+Tab not working in Jupyter Notebook in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm using Jupyter Notebook.

I'm trying to see a function description like this:

[image: sample mouseover with documentation]

When I try the same thing in the Jupyter Notebook, it shows nothing.
I've tried to press Shift + Tab but it's not working.

[image: sample output with no mouseover]

Comment: It's weird, it should be working. You are using Jedi Language Server, but both Jedi and Pylance working on my computer. It does not work when you hover your mouse on the `print` in the Jupyter NoteBook? What about the Ctrl+Click?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT hey Steven, well i didnt even knew i was using jedi language server tbh, i tried to hover my mouse in the print but nothing shows up, tried to Ctrl+Click, and Shift+Tab and nothing shows :/

Comment: did you install the Jupyter extension? In the first screenshot, are you hovering your mouse over the `print` function?

Answer (score 8):

For MacOS press SHIFT + COMMAND + SPACE within functions' parentheses.

For Windows or Linux press CTRL + SHIFT + SPACE within functions' parentheses

Or simply hover the cursor for a sec

Comment: Is there any way to remap the keys for this shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, when you hover over a function, it not only displays the function's arguments but also provides information about the types of those arguments. This feature enhances your coding experience by giving you insights into the function's expected input types. As suggested by "Gri Ziz," it makes your life easier by offering contextual information while you're writing code